# Let $C(0,1)$ be the real linear space of all real functions continuous on ...

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

How a operator can be shown to be skew symmetric. Here the space is not finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

By definition we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}( Tf,g)&=&\int_0^1\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right) g(x)dx
\\&=&\int\int_{0\leq t\leq x \leq 1}f(t) g(x)dt\,dx
\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Similarly we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}( Tg,f)&=&\int_0^1\left(\int_0^tg(x)dx\right) f(t)dt
\\&=&\int\int_{0\leq x\leq t \leq 1}f(t) g(x)dt\,dx
\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Adding we get:

\begin{eqnarray*}( Tf,g)+(Tg,f)&=&\int\int_{0\leq t\leq x \leq 1}f(t) g(x)dt\,dx
+\int\int_{0\leq x\leq t \leq 1}f(t) g(x)dt\,dx\\&=&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(t) g(x)dt\,dx\\&=&\int_0^1 0 dx =0,
\end{eqnarray*}
as required.

Comment: how we have got the last lines, that is, how we can combine two sums into a single one

Comment: The intersection of the sets $\Omega_1:=\{(t,x) \colon 0\leq t\leq x\leq 1\}$ and $\Omega_2:= \{ (t,x) \colon 0\leq x\leq t \leq 1\}$ is $I:=\{ (x,t)\colon x=t\}$ and hence of measure 0, so we can treat them as disjoint sets and simply use summation of integrals for disjoint sets. 
(More specifically, you can subtract the intersection from one of the two sets without changing the value of the summand and then consider the integrals over $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2\setminus I$)

Comment: ok. thats fine. Thank you,

Comment: We are integrating the same function in both integrals, just over different triangular regions of the unit square: $\{x,t|\,\, 0\leq x\leq 1,\,0\leq t\leq 1\}$, so we can combine into a single integral over the whole square (ignoring the diagonal overlap for the reason given by @J.Becker).